# read browser home page using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

All previous answers I found use *`window.home()`* or some other calls that are either outdated or browser specific and do not work anymore. Any elegant solution for modern browsers? At least `IE 11`.

Comment: There is no replacement and it really is not needed. Anyone can open a new tab and get what they want.

Comment: User needs to add param value in URL used in Browser Home and I need to read it and create new URL based on that.

Comment: Why do you need it like this? What problem are you trying to solve using this method? What is this feature actually for? There is probably a better (and not impossible, like this one) way.

Comment: You can not read the browser urls/settings if it is not part of your webpage.

Comment: You want to find out the URLs of your visitors' homepages? That would be a massive invasion of privacy!

Comment: @Quentin no this is in intranet we control all clients(browsers) and web app itself. We need each browser to identify itself and send specific number assigned to it. Browser admin will set this value in it's home and then by using JS we will dynamically create the link on application home, when clicked and request sent to server - we will not exactly where did request come from. We must use URL params for this. Hope this explains intentions

Comment: @reg since you control all browsers and want to set specific options for each of them, why not change their user agent string (end probably filter it before it goes outside your intranet, to prevent leaking internal information)? That way you could get info for every request, not just that single click on home page (what's more - if homepage is loaded from intranet server, you would get info right away, without a need for a click).